# Button onClick not working in React x Laravel

Tags: javascript, reactjs, laravel, onclick

Hello everyone i am quite lost right now, in my other react projects onClick is working just fine but now with my new app laravel with react i cannot do an Onclick this is crazy i dont know where the problem is because i have no error in the console...

**EDIT**

I finally found the problem, i imported twice a js file in my layout

```
   
    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>

    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{  asset('css/bootstrap.css')}}">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    @if (Auth::user())
        @include('inc.navbar') 
    @endif

        <main class="py-4">
            @yield('content')
        </main>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
```

Comment: Use `window.alert("Dallan")` because you cannot use `alert()` directly in react

Comment: is there any error showing in console of browser ? check if you can put type="button" it work ?

Comment: I always used alert() and it worked, but i tried window.alert but not working also

Comment: I got no errors in my console, i don't know what is going on

Comment: please copy the complete file content to show us more about the problem

Comment: @mmantach i edit it

Answer (score 0):

can you try please to add to the button tag ( type="button" ) , if its not working try to remove the taskform component to check if there is error in the component

Comment: No still nothing...

Answer (score 0):

I also just faced this problem when using laravel 8 mix react 17, the solution is to downgrade to react 16.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).